# Link error with MSVC but not with g++ with constexpr

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct FactoryTag
{
    static struct Shape {} shape;
    static struct Color {} color;
};

template <typename TFactory>
int factoryProducer(TFactory tag)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TFactory, FactoryTag::Shape>::value)
        return 12;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<TFactory, FactoryTag::Color>::value)
        return 1337;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << factoryProducer(FactoryTag::shape) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine with `g++ -std=c++1z Main.cpp` but in Visual Studio with MSVC set with c++17 support it gives

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct FactoryTag::Shape FactoryTag::shape" (?shape@FactoryTag@@2UShape@1@A) StaticTest  C:\Users\danielj\source\repos\StaticTest\StaticTest\StaticTest.obj  1
```

Is this a bug in MSVC?

Comment: You can fix this by using `static inline constexpr struct Shape {} shape{}; static inline constexpr struct Color {} color{};` that is by providing definitions for those static members.

Comment: @VTT, you don't need `inline` for `constexpr` they are already inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug in MSVC?

No, `FactoryTag::shape` is *odr-used* here, so it needs a definition (you're copy-constructing it, which goes through the implicitly generated copy constructor, which requires you to bind a reference). Nor is this a bug in gcc either, arguably, since there is [no diagnostic required](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10.sentence-1) if a definition is missing.

The solution is to add a definition. The old way would be:

```
struct FactoryTag { ... };

Shape FactoryTag::shape{}; // somewhere in a source file
```

The new way would be:

```
struct FactoryTag {
    struct Shape {} static constexpr shape {}; // implicitly inline in C++17
};
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is meant with 'no diagnostic required'?

Comment: @J.Daniel A diagnostic is a message the compiler gives you about something bad that you did (could be an error, could be a warning). Typically, the compiler is required to give you a message about things that you did wrong. But sometimes, it might be really hard to actually figure that out - so the standard doesn't require a diagnostic. This is one of those cases.